# How to capture browser get/post requests use java?

Tags: java, http, capture

How to capture browser get/post requests use java?  just like fiddler or badboy，attention: it's not use fiddler to capture java requests!!!

Comment: Capture them from where?  From the browser?  (In the browser?) On the network?  On the server?  Out of thin air? (This question is unclear)

Comment: Or ... are you asking ... how do I implement Fiddler in Java?  (Too broad a question!)

Comment: sorry about that,  capture all request information from browser like Fiddler, please don't care if the question is too broad, just anwser it, thanks

Comment: *"Please don't care if the question is too broad, just answer it."* - Here is the broad answer. 1) read the HTTP specs, 2) research server-side frameworks or libraries, 3) choose one, 4) design your java fiddler, 5) code it, 6) test it, .... 7) profit.

Comment: Or plan B: employ someone to do all of that work for you.   Or plan C: search for an existing tool that does what you need.  (But note that we cannot help you with either "plan B" or "plan C".  They are both off-topic.)